# PHP snmp return result

Tags: php, snmp

I use this function for get result by snmp
`snmp2_walk("localhost", "private", "OID");`

All work fine, but result returns in this form:
STRING: "..."
STRING: "second"

Is there a function to convert this result into a normal string?
From `STRING: "second"` to `second`

Comment: Well, _type matters_ for snmp, I personally prefer getting it with the value. AFAIK there is no way to omit it, but you can just `$data = explode(':',$value,2);` to get them separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
snmp_set_quick_print(1); // print just the value, no types
snmp_set_valueretrieval(SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN); // no quotes for strings
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.snmp.php

Comment: If `snmp_set_quick_print` is not set `snmpget()` sometimes returns the output in different format. Once in few tries it returns the object type with the value, which can cause problems.
Your solution solves this problem as well.